# In a primary-secondary Mongo db set if you accidentally write to a secondary would it reflect in primary it gets routed to primary

Tags: mongodb

In our mongodb set we have 1 primary and 3 secondaries. Accidentally a write was done on a secondary and the write was updated to other members including a primary.Not sure if the update was routed to primary or that a  write to a secondary is possible in mongodb?One of the members was under recovery mode during the time.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible. A Primary is the only writable one. In a fail-over situation, a secondary may take over being primary, but data is always written to the one and only primary and replicated to secondaries. As a downed-primary recovers, it would sync data before taking primaryship.

Comment: I was actually under the same impression writes wouldn't be allowed on secondaries. we had switched the primary to a secondary and primary was set as secondary earlier. But still it was a set of one primary and 3 secondaries one of which was under recovering mode when the update was done  and it showed up on all three servers we even tested to see by updating a few records and it showed up on all the servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to write to a secondary in MongoDB replica set.

If the write succeeded it went to a primary (from there it replicates to all secondaries).

The state of other nodes (recovering, startup) is not relevant to this.  Secondaries simply cannot accept writes (except via the replication mechanism).

Comment: Any idea if there's a Mongo-like DB that *does* support writing to "secondaries"? Thanks!

Comment: They wouldn't be secondaries then, would they? :)

Comment: Hence the quotes :)
I'll be looking into Cassandra, might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: couchdb is decentralized, should be possible there!