# Write to mongo db replica set: take care of primary when writing?

Tags: mongodb

My mongo db has one primary node and two secondary nodes.

Do I have to take care, which node is the primary node when writing?
Or does mongo db automatically redirect write operations from a secondary node to the primary node?

A similar question is  discussed here, but my question got not answered clearly there:
[In a primary-secondary Mongo db set if you accidentally write to a secondary would it reflect in primary it gets routed to primary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443814/in-a-primary-secondary-mongo-db-set-if-you-accidentally-write-to-a-secondary-wou)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really all about how you configure your connection string to your replica set and how the driver is able to "discover" the members correctly.

To specifically cover the statement made on the referenced question, it is not possible to write to a secondary as writes only go to the primary within a set. In the event of a failure for a primary node, a **new** primary needs to be elected. During this period when the election is held, write operations will **fail** as there is currently no primary to service them.

As for the specific mechanics of "how" the driver determines which is the current "primary", there is more detail in the [meta spec for driver implementations](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/connect-driver-to-replica-set/).

But the general case is that as long as you specify "enough" of the possible hosts to contact for the replica set ( and all of them is a good case for three nodes ), then the driver is able to "inspect" the members and determine which one is the "primary" and available to write to.

So the "failover" is part of the replica set configuration, and the "detection" is done by the driver, where that can talk to "at least one node" and ask that to return which node is the current primary, so that can then be used for future write operations.

Comment: abstract: the redirection to the right node is the job of the mongodb driver

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways of how to set it up have a look at this link: [MongoDB Replica Members](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-members/)

At the end you would need to have configuration server running (mongos) and that would redirect your request transparently for read/write depending on the setup. However it is also possible to do this on application level.