# mongodb - write operations are rejected when primary node down

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

We have one primary and two secondary nodes on mongo, during autoscale the primary goes down and secondary(whichever is healthy) becomes a new primary using election. At this time no write operations are allowed, the mongo simply rejects the write queries with the below error.

```
"errmsg": "not master",
"code": 10107,
"codeName": "NotWritablePrimary",
```

We also faced the error `not master and slaveOk=false` but after setting `readPreference=primaryPreferred` in the connection string reads are allowed during primary is down.

The reason for autoscale is the load at peak hours, which is expected and hence it gets automatically scaled to a higher number. After exploring found below things

[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26091582/6582942)

> In the event of a failure for a primary node, a new primary needs to
> be elected. During this period when the election is held, write
> operations will fail as there is currently no primary to service them.

[Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455669/6582942)

> It is not possible to write to a secondary in the MongoDB replica set.

Question: Has anyone faced this before? If it's a known behavior how can we allow write operations during this time? as it affects the application to result in 500 errors. Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Note: We are using MongoDB atlas with replicas. We tried [Test failover](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/test-failover/#std-label-test-failover-process) of Atlas to simulate the autoscaling and then did a small load test to perform reads and writes on DB.
We are using the following

- NodeJs: v12
- NPM: v6
- NestJS: v6
- `@nestjs/mongoose`: v6.4

Connection String options are

```
retryWrites=true&w=majority&readPreference=primaryPreferred
```

Answer (score 2):

It is expected behaviour during the election duration(typically not exceeding 12 sec )  to have the replicaSet readOnly  , you may enable [retryable writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/retryable-writes/#std-label-retryable-writes) to allow the driver to do one more attempt after serverSelectionTimeoutMS  milliseconds ( default 30000ms )

Comment: thanks for the tip, retryWrites is already enabled, updated question +1

Comment: Good find ! That was a tricky one. Thanks. This deserves an upvote.